# C++ operators '&' and '*' with invalid pointer

Tags: c++

In C++, we can use '*' to get the value of a pointer and '&' to get the address (pointer) of a value. But I met something confusing when using these operators on an invalid pointer.

Here are my test codes:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B
{
public:
    B() { x = 10; }
    int x;
    int GetX() { return x; }
};

class A
{
public:
    B* b;
    A()
    {
        b = nullptr;
    }
    B* GetB() { return b; }
};

int main()
{
    A * a = new A();

    B ib = *a->GetB();
    B * pb = &ib;
    B * pb2 = a->GetB();

    if (nullptr != pb2)
    {
        cout << "pb2 is not nullptr" << endl;
        //cout << pb2->GetX() << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "pb2 is nullptr" << endl;
    }

    if (nullptr != pb)
    {
        cout << "pb is not nullptr" << endl;
        //cout << pb->GetX() << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "pb is nullptr" << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The codes are built in vs2015 with release(x86) mode. 
And here is the output:

```
pb2 is nullptr
pb is not nullptr
```

It is confusing that the pointer `pb` can pass the nullptr test. If I remove the annotation symbol `//` at line `//cout << pb->GetX() << endl;`, thus I get a memory crash at this line.

Why `pb` can pass the nullptr test?

Comment: `*a->GetB()` is *undefined behavior* as you dereference a null pointer.

Comment: nitpick: "*' to get the value of a pointer " no, if `ptr` is a pointer then `ptr` **is** the value of the pointer. `*ptr` dereferences the pointer and gives you the value the pointer is pointing to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simplify the code a lot:

```
int a;
int *pa = &a;
```

The variable `a` exists, there's no doubt about it I hope. There's memory reserved for it by the compiler *somewhere*.

By using `&a` you get a pointer to the variable `a`, and that pointer can simply never be a null pointer.

It's the same in your code:

```
B ib;
B* pb = &ib;
```

The variable `ib` exists, no matter how you initialize it, and a pointer to it will never be a null pointer.

---

As for `pb2` being a null pointer, it's because the `GetB` function returns a null pointer.

The `GetB` function can, with the current code, be simplified as

```
B* GetB() { return nullptr; }
```

When you then do

```
B* pb2 = a->GetB();
```

you simply initialize `pb2` as a null pointer. It's equivalent to

```
B* pb2 = nullptr;
```

Comment: what about the `*a->GetB()` part?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 While it's bad, it's really irrelevant for this.

Comment: i didnt really understand the quesitons so i'll just trust you and get a coffee ;)